# Merging streams parallel vs. serial

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have two streams in a gulpfile.

```
const merge2 = require('merge2');

let stream1 = gulp.src('file1.txt');
let stream2 = gulp.src('file2.txt');
```

Then I output the merged stream to a destination (There are various transformations, which are omitted for the sake of clarity).

```
let combined = ... \\ merge the streams, using one of the methods
                   \\ shown below. then,
combined.pipe(gulp.dest('build'));
```

I am using [`merge2`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/merge2) to merge the two streams. The API specifies two ways to do this:

```
// parallel
combined = merge2([stream1, stream2]);
```

Or,

```
// serial
combined = merge2(stream1, stream2);
```

Both serial *and* parallel merges produce the same output for me.

I understand that there must be a difference between the two merge methods. I have checked [Node.js's streams API](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html) and various other sources, however, I cannot find any documentation about the difference of the two methods.

Could someone let me know the difference between parallel vs. serial merging for streams?

Comment: does it matter ? i mean you get the desired result, serial will just iterate over the array of stream and move to next while parallel will pretty much do the same in js iterate over the array and produce the result based on elements order while all tasks dont start in order when they finish, again the elements are delivered in order. at least thats how i understand the theory of it. For ex. `Promise.all` will call resolve when all tasks are finished although the tasks don't really start in order..

Comment: @Gntem: That's what it looks like to me too. But just curious if this will make any difference when used with a transformation, etc..

Comment: i believe it won't make any difference with transforming an stream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, **no**, there is no difference.

If you do not provide an Array, `merge2` will do it by itself, converting the non-Array arguments to Arrays. The possibility might just be there for usability reasons. See the source, line 43:

```
if (!Array.isArray(streams)) streams = [streams]
```

https://github.com/teambition/merge2/blob/master/index.js#L43